# c++ compiling "error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token "

Tags: c++

Very simple codes located in the same file 'foo.h':

```
class Xface
{
  public:
    uint32_t m_tick;
    Xface(uint32_t tk)
    {
      m_tick=tk;
    }
}

std::map<uint32_t, Xface*> m;

Xface* tmp;

tmp = new Xface(100);  **//Error**
m[1] = tmp;  **//Error**

tmp = new Xface(200);  **//Error**
m[2] = tmp;  **//Error**
```

The error is 
**error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token**
for every assignment.

Comment: i have included the <map>.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 8):

C++ is not a scripting language. You can declare items outside the bounds of an executable block of code, but you cannot do any processing. Try moving the erroring code into a function like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::map<uint32_t, Xface*> m;

    Xface* tmp;

    tmp = new Xface(100);  **//Error**
    m[1] = tmp;  **//Error**

    tmp = new Xface(200);  **//Error**
    m[2] = tmp;  **//Error**
}
```

Comment: Yeah, how awesome, if you could just code like in `python`, right after class ;-)

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me!

Comment: I don't think the assignment of `m[1] = tmp;` is part of his problem. I have declared `static unsigned char montbl[13] = { 0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31 };` outside of function before. Why would the `m[1] = tmp;` assignment fail outside of a function? Technically you should be able to perform assignment outside of a function.

Comment: @0A0D: `montbl` is the definition of a global variable (plus its initialization). Definitions are allowed at namespace scope. `m[1]=tmp;` is an assignment, and such statements are not allowed at namespace scope.

Answer (score 4):

Your code must be inside some function, you can't just put it in void :-) Try running the same code in main and see, what happens.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Xface
{
  public:
    uint32_t m_tick;
    Xface(uint32_t tk)
    {
      m_tick=tk;
    }
}    // need a semicolon here
```

You are missing a semicolon at the end of the class definition.

Comment: thanks, that was my typo. But it still does not work after i added the ;.
I will try the answer of 'Randolpho' posted below.

Answer (score 2):

You have no default constructor.  You need to have a constructor that doesn't need any arguments.  Right now, you've got a constructor that needs a `uint32_t`, so you can't `new` an array of them.  Not to mention, as Neil pointed out, the missing semicolon, and gruszczy's observation that executable code needs to be in a function.